# ODBC connection failed error in Excel 64-bit

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a linked table in ms-access which is linked to a sql server table, and when I am trying to fetch the data in excel via VBA from ms-access linked table the error message "ODBC connection failed" showing.

Note:- I am manually successfully able to refresh ms-access linked table in ms-access, "peoplemain" is the name of linked table.

Note:- When I tried to fetch data from non linked table, it is running successfully.

Below code is working in Excel-32 bit version, but not working in excel-64 bit.

[code]

```
Sub FetchData()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As String

conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\Workflow Tools (Michael Cantor)\Tool For Fixing Bug From Michael Cantor\PI MDT Reconciliation Workflow Tool\SampleforPractice.accdb;"


Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open conn

rs.Open "Select * from peoplemain", cn  'Error Line



Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks

Kashif

Answer (score 0):

I would try out setting a `strSQL` as a string like this (I had the same issue you did and when I made the change it worked for me):

```
Sub FetchData()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As String, strSQL AS String

conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\Workflow Tools (Michael Cantor)\Tool For Fixing Bug From Michael Cantor\PI MDT Reconciliation Workflow Tool\SampleforPractice.accdb;"

strSQL = "Select * from peoplemain"


Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open conn

rs.Open strSQL , cn  'Error Line



Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, yes it is working on first time only and when I tried to run 3 or 4 times again showing the same error.

Comment: Hi All experts, I am kindly requesting all of you please please help me to resolve this problem, I am not able to understand why it is not working in link table. Thanks Kashif

Comment: if its working on tables that are not linked then I would remove the link for this table as well.

Comment: I can not remove the link because, that table is referencing in other queries and we need live refresh live data in this table from SQL Server, and if we remove the link the refresh data will not come in this table.